# How to use the for loop over multiple criteria in mongodb from spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to use the for loop over the criteria in the spring Dao to return a list of documents for each scenario matched in the list:

1. mongoDb contains multiple documents for the same studentId with different times.
2. I have a Array list with studentId's and times that I want to query on mongodb

**The input looks like this**

```
List <StudentAssociation> ={{studentId:st1234,assocstarttime=2019-08-16,assocendtime:2019-08-17},{studentId:st3456,assocstarttime=2019-07-09, assocendtime=2019-08-15}}
```

The query I wrote for a single student working without the for loop, but I want to send the list as the input

**Working query**

```
public List<Student> getListOfStudentRecords(String studentId, LocalDateTime assocstarttime, LocalDatetime assocendtime) {

Query query = new Query();
    Criteria studentIdCriteria = Criteria
            .where("studentId)
            .is(studentId);

    Criteria dateTimeCriteria = Criteria
            .where(datetime)
            .gte(assocstarttime.toString())
            .lte(assocendtime.toString());

    query.addCriteria(studentIdCriteria);
    query.addCriteria(dateTimeCriteria);
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Student.class); 
 }
```

**What I am trying is input the list, the following query**

public List getListofStudentRecordsUsingList(List studentAssoc) {

```
Query query = new Query();
   //for loop
 for(StudentAssociation sa : studentAssoc) {
     Criteria studentIdCriteria = Criteria
            .where("studentId)
            .is(studentId);
    Criteria dateTimeCriteria = Criteria
            .where(datetime)
            .gte(sa.getAssocStarttime())
            .lte(sa.getAssocEndtime());
    query.addCriteria(studentIdCriteria);
    query.addCriteria(dateTimeCriteria);
    }
    query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, datetime));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, Student.class);
}
```

Expected output is for each student in the list return list of documents and then merge the result for each student into a single list and sort based on time field to create a timeline

**The error I am getting withe second query is**
//this is solved when I moved the Query query = new Query(); inside the for Loop

InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'studentId' criteria. Query already contains '{ "lStudentId" : "st1234" }' //this is resolved when I move the query inside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query object definition is outside of loop, so the same object is used for your whole loop. At second pass, query variable already contains a 'studentId' criteria, as explained in your error.
Try to set query inside loop, or clear your object at start of loop.

```
   //for loop
 for(StudentAssociation sa : studentAssoc) {
    Query query = new Query();
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add the result from each studentID into one collection and merge to create a timeline

Answer (score 0):

Query in a loop is such an expensive thing, i would recommend you to use `and` & `in` for reduce the number of queries.
Mongodb provides operator  like :

> The $and operator evaluates one or more expressions and returns true if all of the expressions are true or if evoked with no argument expressions. Otherwise, $and returns false.
>
> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```
Query findStudent = new Query(Criteria.where("studentId").in('List of id')
            .and('datetime').gte('you should filter min time')
            .lte('max time'))
            .with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, datetime));
```

Comment: Tha date parameters change for each studentId in List<Student>. I cant manually declare dates